# String == operator: how did Microsoft write it?

Tags: c#, string, compare

I want to know how Microsoft write algorithm for string comparison.

```
string.equal and string.compare
```

Do they compare character by character like this:

```
int matched = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
{
    if (str1[i] == str2[i])
    {
        matched++;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
if (matched == str1.Length) return true;
```

Or match all at once

```
if (str1[0] == str2[0] && str1[1] == str2[1] && str1[2] == str2[2]) return true;
```

I trying pressing F12 on the string.equal function but it got me to the function declaration not the actual code. Thanks

> After Thilo mentioned to look at the source i was able to find this... this is how Microsoft wrote it.

```
public static bool Equals(String a, String b) {
    if ((Object)a==(Object)b) {
        return true;
    }

    if ((Object)a==null || (Object)b==null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (a.Length != b.Length)
        return false;

    return EqualsHelper(a, b);
}
```

But this raise a question whether is faster by checking character by character or doing a complete match?

Comment: In what language, specifically what functions?

Comment: You could look at the source. Usually people check the length first, then a hashcode if available, then character by character.

Comment: C# is the language i am looking for the function is mentioned in the post dude (string.equal or string.compare). How do i look at the source?

Comment: Start here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c

Comment: What do you mean by a 'complete match'?

Comment: Like if h1 == h1 && h2 == h2 && h3 == h3.... using if and. But doesnt matter now, as i understand it Thanks

Comment: both of your example comparisons compare character by character - how else would it even be possible? (without using extra space for additional information like a precalculated hash code for diff optimizations)

Comment: Your 'complete match' example is hard coded for strings that are 3 characters long. It is not possible to code for variable length strings like that.

Comment: Yes but the first example avoids unnecessary check while the second one doesnt

Comment: `&&` still shortcuts, and does avoid "unnecessary checks".

Comment: You second example will also avoid unnecessary comparisons as the `&&` operator will not evaluate the second operand if the first is false. The problem with that way of doing things is that you don't know how long the string is.

Comment: Ahh nice ... cheers @Ergwun i always though that it will still carries on doing the && check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c) (copied below):

1. null check
2. reference identity
3. different length => not equal
4. go over the binary encoding of the characters in a bit of an unrolled loop

> this raise a question whether is faster by checking character by character or doing a complete match

I don't understand the question. You cannot do a "complete match" without checking each of the characters. What you can do is bail out as soon as you find a mismatch. That reduces runtime a bit, but does not change the fact that it is O(n).

---

```
        // Determines whether two strings match.
        [Pure]
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
        public bool Equals(String value) {
            if (this == null)                        //this is necessary to guard against reverse-pinvokes and
                throw new NullReferenceException();  //other callers who do not use the callvirt instruction

            if (value == null)
                return false;

            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, value))
                return true;

            if (this.Length != value.Length)
                return false;

            return EqualsHelper(this, value);
        }

        [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
        private unsafe static bool EqualsHelper(String strA, String strB)
        {
            Contract.Requires(strA != null);
            Contract.Requires(strB != null);
            Contract.Requires(strA.Length == strB.Length);

            int length = strA.Length;

            fixed (char* ap = &strA.m_firstChar) fixed (char* bp = &strB.m_firstChar)
            {
                char* a = ap;
                char* b = bp;

                // unroll the loop
      #if AMD64
                // for AMD64 bit platform we unroll by 12 and
                // check 3 qword at a time. This is less code
                // than the 32 bit case and is shorter
                // pathlength

                while (length >= 12)
                {
                    if (*(long*)a     != *(long*)b) return false;
                    if (*(long*)(a+4) != *(long*)(b+4)) return false;
                    if (*(long*)(a+8) != *(long*)(b+8)) return false;
                    a += 12; b += 12; length -= 12;
                }
      #else
                while (length >= 10)
                {
                    if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) return false;
                    if (*(int*)(a+2) != *(int*)(b+2)) return false;
                    if (*(int*)(a+4) != *(int*)(b+4)) return false;
                    if (*(int*)(a+6) != *(int*)(b+6)) return false;
                    if (*(int*)(a+8) != *(int*)(b+8)) return false;
                    a += 10; b += 10; length -= 10;
                }
       #endif

                // This depends on the fact that the String objects are
                // always zero terminated and that the terminating zero is not included
                // in the length. For odd string sizes, the last compare will include
                // the zero terminator.
                while (length > 0) 
                {
                    if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) break;
                    a += 2; b += 2; length -= 2;
                }

                return (length <= 0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ahh so it does check character by character

Comment: Essentially, yes. It actually checks bigger chunks in one go, but that's still the same idea.